# C# ICollection extension

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, unity-game-engine

I would like to write a C# extension for generic Array but it's always casting an Error. Here is the code i used to create extendsion for string[] which works well :

```
public static string[] Add(this string[] list, string s, bool checkUnique = false, bool checkNull = true){
    if (checkNull && string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return list;
    if (checkUnique && list.IndexOf(s) != -1) return list;

    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    arr.AddRange(list);
    arr.Add(s);

    return (string[])arr.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

What i really want is do it more generic so it will also works for other types not only string (so i tried to replace all string specifics with generics T) :

```
public static T[] Add(this T[] list, T item, bool checkUnique = false){
    if (checkUnique && list.IndexOf(item) != -1) return list;

    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    arr.AddRange(list);
    arr.Add(item);

    return (T[])arr.ToArray(typeof(T));
}
```

but the code won't compile. It's casting an error "error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

I already tried another solution around :

```
public static void AddIfNotExists<T>(this ICollection<T> coll, T item) {
     if (!coll.Contains(item))
         coll.Add(item);
 }
```

but it's casting another error "error CS0308: The non-generic type `System.Collections.ICollection' cannot be used with the type arguments"

As a side note, I'm using Unity C# (which is compiles against 3.5 I think). Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You're method is not setup to use a generic type... `public static T[] Add<T>(...) { }` is the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last method does not compile because of the missing reference to the System.Collections.Generic namespace.  You seem to have included the reference to System.Collections only.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use LINQ and make your method a bit simpler:

```
    public static T[] Add<T>(this T[] list, T item, bool checkUnique = false)
    {
        var tail = new [] { item, };
        var result = checkUnique ? list.Union(tail) : list.Concat(tail);
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the method signature to this:

```
public static T[] Add<T>(this T[] list, T item, bool checkUnique = false)
{}
```

However, there are no generic methods for T[] so `list.IndexOf(item)` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your last code should work **IF** you are **NOT** calling it for string arrays, as arrays have fixed sizes!

The following exampl works for me with your extension method that uses `ICollection`:

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>();
arr.AddIfNotExists("a");
```